# Video Reader in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am newbie in Matlab. I want to read a video file and I am trying this command `video=mmread('Hello.avi');` but I am getting this error:

> ??? Undefined function or method 'mmread9' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Comment: You seem to have a typo either in the error or your code, because `mmread` is not the same as `mmread9`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mmread()` is not built in to Matlab. But you can [download it at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8028-mmread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8028-mmread)